# Reloading telerik grid asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

i have the following grid on my asp.net mvc project

```
<div class="actualGrid" id="actualGrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AVNO_KPMG.Models.Bench>()    //Bench Grid
        .Name("grid")

    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.name).Title("Bench").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains"))).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.freeSeats).Title("Free Seats").Width(250).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("gte")))
            .ClientTemplate("<div class='barthingy'><div class='bars_text'><div class='seatsText'><img src=\"/images/booked_full_15x15.png\" /> <b>#=bookedSeats#</b> USED SEATS</div><div class='seatsText'><img src=\"/images/booked_15x15.png\" /> <b>#=freeSeats#</b> TOTAL OFSEATS</div></div><div id='bigbar'><div  class='bigbar'  style='width:100%; float:left; background-color:rgb(142, 188, 0);'><div  ' style='float:right; width:#=bookedSeats *100 / seatsCount#%; background-color:rgb(255, 99, 71); height:16px '  class='b_#=name#' id='temp-log'></div></div></div></div>");

        //buttons
        columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("checkBench1 ").Text(" AM ").Click("doCheckIn"); command.Custom("checkBench 2").Text(" PM ").Click("doCheckIn"); command.Custom("checkBench3").Text("All Day").Click("doCheckIn"); }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "comms" }).Title("Check in");

    })

    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()

    .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(false))
            .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
            //.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:530px;" })
            .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(10)
    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetBenches", "Home"))
            )
    )
</div>
```

after i do some things on the page i want the grid to refresh 
i tried with

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.fetch();
```

and

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.read();
```

but with no luck. is there another way of refresh this grid?

Comment: sometimes the Read action can become cached since the parameters havent changed since the last call.. make sure you are hitting a break point inside your read action.. if not you can use the `[OutputCache(Duration=0)]` attribute in your controller on your action

Answer (score 0):

You also need to refresh the UI:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.read();
grid.refresh();
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-refresh

Comment: Are you hitting the script code and the Read action?

Comment: Yes i havê console.log before and after

Comment: Maybe ajax is caching it? http://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-ajax-caching-on-read